# Returning an attribute from flex to bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, context-free-grammar, flex-lexer

i am trying yo write some kind of a simple compiler that detects undeclared variable, and does some extra stuff. The problem is, i cannot use "$$" in my bison file, it says **"$$ of `type' has no declared type"**. Here are the related parts of my flex and bison files:

```
flx file:

int[ \t\n]+matrix {yylval.type_id.Type = 4;return tINTMATRIXTYPE; }
```

---

```
bison file:

%}

%union semrec
{
struct
{
  int Type;
  char *id;
 }type_id;
}

%start prog



%%
prog: stmtlst
;

stmtlst : stmt
    | stmt stmtlst
;

tmt : decl //baktım
     | asgn
     | if
;

decl : type vars '=' expr ';' 
;

type : tINTTYPE     
     | tINTVECTORTYPE    
     | tINTMATRIXTYPE   {$$.Type=$1.Type;}
     | tREALTYPE         
     | tREALVECTORTYPE    
     | tREALMATRIXTYPE    
;




%%
```

Writing $1.Type in bison file works, but $$.Type does not work.
Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell bison what type each token is (both terminal and non-terminal) that you plan on assigning a value to.  It also looks like you don't have any of your tokens declared either.

```
%type <Type> type
```

Will get you started.  But now you'll have to ensure $$ is set for all of the other types (tINTTYPE, etc) as well.

Here's a simple example that should give you a general gist of how bison operates: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html

Comment: flex/bison are fun and powerful little tools, but can be tricky to figure out at first. Definitely post if you have any more issues.  Out of curiosity, what is the context of this project?

Comment: Thanks, actually ii have one more question. About your question, the context of project is that, we write a scanner and semantic analyzer for basic math operations. We did syntactic issues in the previous step, now we have to detect semantic errors. 1)Undeclared variable 2)Comparison of a matrix or vector with an integer, real etc. My other question is, i can do something like this: %token <type_Type> <type_id> tIDENT but i cant do the following: 
%type <type_Type> <type_id> vars. I mean, if it is a token, then i can associate it with 2 attributes, but if it is a type i can't.

Comment: what can i do about it? @Josh

Comment: You shouldn't be able to associate either tokens or types with multiple elements in the union.  The grammar you posted is structured so you shouldn't have to.

Comment: But i want to keep both id and Type information with the nonterminal "vars" or "value". How can i do this?

Comment: Then you'll need to create a custom struct that holds both types of information, and put it as a member in the union.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27969/discussion-between-bigo-and-josh)